# how to prove that $k+1 \ge (1+\frac{1}{k})^{k}$?

Tags: analysis

How to prove that
$$k+1\ge \bigg(1+\frac{1}{k}\bigg)^{k}
$$    when $k>2$

Comment: If $k=-2$, then LHS < RHS.

Comment: prove when k>2.

Comment: RHS is an increasing sequence bounded up by e

Comment: I know it, but how to prove without lim, when we had to prove that we hadn't passed bounded sequences and e.

Comment: Worked it out in my head, but too late in my time zone to post it, but here's a hint: consider the binomial expansion of the RHS. What can you say about the upper bound on each term? How many terms are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will prove this with induction.

Consider the base case of $k=2$. Clearly, $3\ge 2.25$.

Now assume that $k+1\ge \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$. We want to show that $\left(k+1\right)+1\ge\left(1+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}$. Consider

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}&=\left(1+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^k\left(1+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\
&\le\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k\left(1+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\
&\le\left(k+1\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\
&=(k+1)+\frac{k+1}{k+1}\\
&=(k+1)+1
\end{align}$$